# The tabs on the user profile pages are showing up in Portuguese

Tags: bug, profile-page

I was just looking at my profile page, and I noticed that the tabs are in Portuguese.

[image: Portuguese tabs]

This behavior seems to occur across browsers even if I am logged out.

It also occurs when viewing *all* profile pages too, not just mine.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce this. It doesn't happen when I look at my profile, or at your profile.

Comment: Did you visit the Portuguese SE beforehand?

Comment: @Makoto Nope. I presume you can't reproduce it? I've cleared my cache/cookies.. it still persists.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it.  I was going to see if we could rule in something like cookies or Local Storage settings.

Comment: Side note, why don't you ever visit the reputation and the response tabs?  Those huge numbers would drive me _crazy_!!!

Comment: yep, it happens for me also. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0n4UB.png

Comment: This was reported earlier on MSE (it seems to be a network wide thing): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250194/portuguese-tab-names-on-profile-page

Comment: @Andy Interesting. Thanks for pointing that out. I wonder why it only occurs for some people... that will be an interesting bug to track down.

Comment: In my case, they're in Portuguese. (I probably wouldn't have noticed had they been in Spanish, but Portuguese is a bit more work.) Is SO pushing us to learn a random new language?

Comment: They're in Portuguese for me and a friend too, though not for another guy.

Comment: Interestingly enough they are in Portuguese on other SE sites, but not on meta.SO..

Comment: They're in Portuguese for me too.  I assume it's not because I'm a fan of Rebeca Matta.  (To add a data point - occurs with both IE11 on Win7 and iceweasel 17.0.10 on debian).

Comment: It's a test of the new Stack Exchange Language Recommender Engine.

Comment: Was about to post this

Comment: I having this problem too...!

Comment: I am also having this. Have not been to Portuguese.SE. Chromium on Linux if that matters.

Comment: Just went to my Stack Overflow em Portuguese and the tabs on my Profile page are in... English. Including on the Portuguese Meta. My SO and MSO are in English.

Comment: Strange to see that the tab "Activities" remains in English and not Portuguese. All tabs are in Portuguese, but one still in English.

Comment: It is curious that in Portuguese StackOverflow, all the tabs are in English - http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2486/partes-da-p%C3%A1gina-de-usu%C3%A1rio-em-ingl%C3%AAs

Comment: @bluefeet: Why would they? Pretty much everything under those tabs is more conveniently available through the top bar inbox / achievements tabs. Well, except for the reputation graph, but I rather prefer the global rep graph at stackexchange.com anyway.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I only do it to remove the notification - my OCD doesn't  like seeing the blue indicator on only a few tabs. I must clear it. :)

Comment: @bluefeet: I'm on enough SE sites that if I tried to do that, I'd spend half my time opening user profiles and clicking tabs. :) I guess if it bothered me, I could always write a user style to hide them... something like `.user-tabs-nav a[href$="?tab=reputation"] .bounty-indicator-tab { display: none }` ought to do it.

Comment: I noticed this yesterday, but today it seems to have fixed itself.

Comment: doesnt happen for me. firefox 35 on ubuntu

Comment: Is this not because you have portuguese in your language settings in your browser?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250194/portuguese-tab-names-on-profile-page now [status-completed].

Answer (score 26):

It happened for me, too. I'm using Firefox 35.0.1 on Linux.

Then I remembered I have NoScript enabled, and allowed only scripts from stackoverflow.com. When I disabled NoScript, the problem went away. However, this was yesterday, today the tabs are in english even with NoScript enabled.

I don't know if this means anything, I just thought I should post it.